# what modifications or methods need for flying monster to withstand thunderstorm?

Tags: science-based, biology, xenobiology, anatomy, natural-defenses

so i want to create a monster that dwell or fly inside thunderstorm as their defense mechanism, though they do goes down to get food, i want to know what method or modifications need for creature to be able to resist thunderstorm or thunderstrike while still able to fly in such environment.

- i am not restricting faraday cage method, but the wing of my monster is full of feather while the rest of the body can be feather or short fur or smooth like human (not decide yet, and i dont know can feather be use like faraday cage or not, so correct me if it possible).
- hence the body wont have long fur,scale,exoskeleton,carapace,shell,etc.
- the body also not made of rubber it just common flesh and blood.
- no rope like organs that touching or buried or connected into the earth.
- the region constantly has thunderstorm in it.
- And as i mention they are monster so they are kinda big like Quetzalcoatlus or as small as pteranodon.

and feel free to edit my grammar and the tag to the appropriate one, (though i appreciate it if this is not removed when you edit it, give other a chance to know that they are welcome to fix or edit this, if theres still some mistake left.

Answer (score 3):

**Salty sweaty beast.**

Birds get hit by lightning.  Google turns up many instances.  My favorite:

[https://www.nature.com/articles/049601c0](Are Birds on the Wing Killed by Lightning?)

> G. W. MURDOCHS  Nature volume 49, page601 (1894)
>
> I CAN answer the question put in NATURE (of April 19) by “Skelfo,” not
>   only from several authentic records in my possession, but from
>   personal observation. Many years ago I was standing on the steps of a
>   woollen mill stair (outside) in the village of the Haugh, Ayrshire, in
>   the company of others, some of whom are still alive, watching a
>   terrific thunderstorm over the fields adjoining the river Ayr. What
>   was then familiarly termed “forked lightning” was playing in the
>   valley with great brilliancy. A lurcher puppy dog chased some ducks
>   from behind an old gas-works building. One bird rose in the air, and
>   with the characteristic cry of fright flew over the millrace in the
>   direction of a corn-field. When on the wing it was struck by lightning
>   and killed “like a shot.” I remember examining the dead bird, but do
>   not remember if it really “smelt villanously of brimstone.” I think
>   not.

Birds, like ourselves, are full of salt water.  Salt water is a fine conductor of electricity; much better than air, and so one cannot blame the bolt for taking an easy shortcut thru handy birds.

My solution: your animal is extremely sweaty, with very salty sweat.  In addition, it has horny protoberances which act as "static wicks". I t replicates the lighting protection of an airplane.

https://www.travelandleisure.com/airlines-airports/why-planes-can-survive-lightning

> Adding to that safety precaution, the skin of airplanes—aluminum in
>   older planes, a composite in more modern models—is designed to conduct
>   electricity off of the plane. When lightning strikes a plane, it sends
>   up to 200,000 amperes of electricity rocketing into the plane’s skin.
>   The electricity follows the outer surface of the plane’s frame and
>   then jumps back into the air, thanks to little antenna-like devices
>   called static wicks...

The salty sweat will route the current around the periphery of the creature, which is hopefully comprised of dispensible orange wool.  This material may char and smell awful but the creature will be OK.

Comment: so you mean to make the monster to be covered in salty sweat to create faraday cage right? or do i get it wrong?

Comment: i kinda get the gist of horny protuberances which i assume is just horn or needle thats not in the head, like platypus or hedgehog kind of needle horn. but google dont give me the meaning or a clear result of it, iam not scientist so i dont know the scientist name of it, so i just ask, just in case i get wrong interpretation of it. also does such method you describe will protect the feather or wings from getting burned? or will it be fine ? (this include the salty sweat) and thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think it is pretty much a sweaty faraday cage.  You are right about the protuberances too.  Sort of a biological lightning rod more or less.

Comment: hey just wondering, would they be fine if they flapping their feather wings or they need to be stiff in order to be safe against thunder strike?

Comment: @LiJun - I think flapping is fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for your monster to fear flying through a lightning storm.  Lightning is caused by an excess of electrons following the path of least resistance  to a a positive charge - the ground below.  Its highly unlikely that your monster offers a lower resistance than the air around it.  Unless your monster was made of metal, it should be perfectly safe from lightning.

Comment: That was my first thought.  It's apparently wrong.  It's not common, but it's also apparently NOT impossible: https://www.nature.com/articles/049601c0

Comment: Hah.  When I went for a cite I found the same one someone else found down below.